# nested divs, jstree display and tablesorter table

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I'm having some issues when it comes to formatting a webapp I'm working.  For some reason when I try to display a table next to a tree it shoves it under the tree instead of beside it.

> [image]

Considering I haven't made a website since 1998 I think I'm doing ok, but anyway here's the code.

```
<div style="height:55px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;float:top;">
    <div id="menu_div" style="height:50px;width:200px;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;display:inline-block;">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick="config_ip()">Configure IP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick="config_local_share()">Configure Local Share</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick="send()">Send Files Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick="help_button()">Allow Remote Access</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Add Source</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" onClick="mysql()">MySQL</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" onClick="mssql()">MSSQL</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" onClick="shareR()">Remote Share</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick="refresh()">Refresh Local Share</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick="backup()">Backup Device</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;margin-top:10px;display:inline-block;">
        <span style="vertical-align:middle;margin-left:20px;"><a href="#" onClick="transfer()"><img src="png/glyphicons_457_transfer.png" /></a></span>
        <span id="deletePic" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-left:20px;"><a href="#" onClick="delete_source()"><img src="png/glyphicons_256_delete.png" /></a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="lower">
    <div id="mainCon" style="width:300px;height:100%;border-right: 1px solid black;float:left;display:inline-block;">
        <div id="browser"></div>
        <div id="subBrowser"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style="float:right;margin-left:320px;display:inline-block;">
            <div id="displayTable"></div> 
            <pre><p style="margin-left:10px;" id="displayText"></p></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use, for the lower block.
vertical-align: top;  display:inline-block;

Comment: nope didn't work.  Sorry should have been a little less brief, but I've been googling this for the last couple of days to no avail.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/jspatel/MN3mt/  you can see it working here.  I colored them red and blue so you can see.

Comment: hmm.. I must have something somewhere else that's messing with it.  Thanks for the help, I'll try to narrow it down more